# What is the fastest character or speedrun build?

Tags: diablo-iii, speedrun

I'm looking to max out my character move speed for running through levels fast (not necessarily clearing enemies or doing high difficulty runs), but I can only find guides on the "fastest leveling methods". Which character build is the fastest, or are speeds about equal on the fastest build for each character? What are the best builds for speedrunning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In speedruns most people tend to use **Demon Hunter** with the [vault skill](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vault).

If you planning to play above level 70 then most classes have some build for speedruns, but my favourite is the Witch Doctor's [Angry Chicken Hex](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/hex) rune with the [Manajuma's Way](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/manajumas-carving-knife) set.

Comment: Demon Hunter is very easy to gear for speedrunning - basically you only need two Hand Crossbows from Danetta's set. Apart from Witch Doctor's Angry Chicken, Crusader also has some speedy builds with [Norvald's Fervor](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/flail-of-the-charge) and [In-Geom](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ingeom) or [Swiftmount](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/swiftmount).

Comment: Monk and Wizard builds have In-Geom variants that effectively give them infinite teleport/dash after killing an elite pack (for 10 seconds) which is usually enough time to find another elite pack.  So they're extremely fast as long as you're killing packs.  A bit less if you're just trying to run as quickly as possible to a location.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't completed speedrun myself, but there are several options for DH Vault skill

### 1. The best option.

Use dual hand crossbow set bonus from [Danetta's Revenge](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/danettas-revenge) + [Danetta's Spire](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/danettas-spite), which make [Vault](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vault) cost only hatred.

Currently nearly all DH builds are using cubed [Dawn](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/dawn) and ideally 38% cooldown reduction on gear (you don't need that much, 20% works pretty well), which let you have constant [Vengeance](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/vengeance) for a massive dps boost. If you use Seethe rune, then it's +10 hatred/sec, letting you cast Vault nearly non-stop.

This works with any build, but have a look at [this particular one](http://www.diablofans.com/builds/85722-2-4-3-ue-danettas-grenades-fast-and-furious-videos), it's not the best for GR (grenades skill doing relatively low dmg output), but it's the most mobile one (don't forget to use Seethe rune!) and give huge survivability (due to ability to keep mobs stunned and infinite vault).

### 2. Good option

Using [Chain of Shadows](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/chain-of-shadows) belt will make Vault free for 2 seconds (2-3 casts) after using Impale.

You will need again cubed Dawn and Vengeance with Seethe rune to cover high cost of Impale, but that's all you need.

Impale, Vault, Vault, Vault, Impale, Vault, Vault, Vault.... you should have an idea.

P.S.: among quick travel options Teleport is the best, you don't need to open doors, you can jump over obstacles, distance is the biggest, so for best results I'd look into it, though I don't have experience with it, let's wait for some sorceresses/monks here ;)

P.P.S.: As DH I can easily outrun any crusader/witch doctor, so I recommend you don't look into those as they are considerably weaker.

Comment: Does that include a crusader using Steed Charge?  I've been running one with near 100% uptime on that the past few days and it's very quick.  But I've never really used a vault DH so I don't have anything to compare to.

Comment: @DanSmolinske, Vault cast covers **big** distance nearly instantly (it's *like* teleport, but it required *path* and distance is shorter, this is why teleport is better), holding pressed button will cast several `Vaults` per second... You should have the idea. Even with high +speed bonus from Crusader/WD skill you are still have to *run* that distance.

Comment: Just a followup - I ended up in a game with a crusader using that setup (I'm doing shadow/impale DH this season) and we were basically tied through the whole rift when going full out in terms of pure movement speed.  DH is by far better dps however, so I think it wins the tiebreaker.

Comment: @DanSmolinske, actually THE FASTEST is the monk. I've done achievement last (9th) season on hardcore (month after answering here lol). It's basically instant teleport, waaay faster any other character (playing wizard feels slow after that), point is its teleport doesn't have cd and with right gear you can basically spam it VERY fast, see [this video](https://youtu.be/3moTA2BAzXc).